# Was Draco affected by the Patronus Charm?

Tags: harry-potter

When Harry was playing nice and clean with his new firebolt, Malfoy and his company tried to disturb Harry by scaring him. Malfoy, who dressed up as a Dementor, tried to scare Harry and knock him off from his broom.

With these circumstances, Harry managed to perform the Patronus Charm, a mist of silver cloud enlarged and hit Malfoy.

Was Malfoy affected by the spell? But a Patronus charm is specialized for Dementors.

Comment: For the record, it's not true that the Patronus is "specialized for Dementors". although it's the only thing that affects them, it is also used against other creatures, such as the [Lethifold](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Lethifold)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They do not appear to have been harmed by Harry's Patronus:

> "You gave Mr. Malfoy quite a fright," said Lupin.
>
> Harry stared. Lying in a crumpled heap on the ground were Malfoy, Crabbe, Goyle, and Marcus Flint, the Slytherin team Captain, all struggling to remove themselves from long, black, hooded robes.
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* Chapter 13: "Gryffindor Versus Ravenclaw"</sup>

They do appear to have fallen over, but whether that was due to a direct impact with the Patronus, or whether they simply recoiled in fright and lost their balance is unclear. For whatever it's worth, [Pottermore does suggest](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/patronus-charm) that corporeal Patronuses<sup>1</sup> have some bodily substance (emphasis mine):

> The incorporeal Patronus is not a true Patronus and while it will give limited protection, it cannot provide the defensive power of the corporeal Patronus, which has **the form and substance of an animal.**
>
> <sup>*Pottermore* Patronus Charm</sup>

But it is of course not clear whether Harry managed a corporeal Patronus in this instance.

---

<sup>1</sup> Patronii? Pantroneese?

Comment: In modern English, Patronuses. In old Latin, Patroni.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Isn't a "latin spelling" still generally acceptable in English? I mean, obviously "octopi" or "virii" are stupid, but "patroni" (or "patrona"?) should be just as valid as "radii"; of course, still implicitly assuming a latin-like lineage, which isn't really discernible for a work like this :) Unless Rowling used a plural form before, I guess we're on dry land here...

Comment: @Luaan The Pottermore article I linked to repeatedly uses "Patronuses", so that's probably the correct plural; I just find alternate pluralizations funny, hence the footnote

Comment: It is possible for a corporeal patronus to affect people, we have seen Ron's patronus dog knock him off in Order of the Phoenix movie. But in the match,  I think Harry only perfomed a simple patronus.

Comment: In _Prisoner of Azkaban_, Harry pats his Patronus when it returns to him after chasing away the Dementors on the other side of the lake. That would support the “substantial” part.

Comment: Yes, i don't think that the patronus was a corporeal stuff. Well, the corporeal was a full summoned patronus that requires deep happiness and focus, but I think Harry only managed to produce a simple patronus that time, the one with a dull silver vapor without the form of animal?

Answer (score 4):

## Nope

I got the impression that Malfoy was only startled by sight of the Patronus.  It would have been very unusual for someone of Harry's age to be able to know how to perform that spell.

I don't believe that the Patronus has any affect on living people apart from the shock/awe factor.

Comment: Possible. But I really don't know if a Patronus Charm can 'touch' or 'knock off' someone.

Comment: @BookStriker - Malfoy is easily scared by the unexpected.  Whether this Patronus was corporeal or not, Malfoy most probably fell off just out of pure fright.